# Aws S3 InvalidAccessKeyId when adding more images months later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attempting to add more assets to my production site, but first I began by attempting to add the image to my development site and when I attempted to save, I got this error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId in PortfoliosController#update

The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
Extracted source (around line #46):

        respond_to do |format|
      if @portfolio_item.update(portfolio_params)
        format.html { redirect_to portfolios_path, notice: 'The record was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
```

I have two other images that I successfully uploaded months ago and are still in my production site, so I do not know why its telling me the AWS Access Key Id I provided does not exist.

Comment: Hello, can you confirm if the access key id is present in your production site? and whether the IAM role exists or not. And whether the access key in the IAM role exist or not. If you confirmed that, check that if your application really use that access key id and not other profiles.

Comment: @KendrickKesley, I saw in my AWS console that I deleted the access key last month. I honestly do not remember why I did that, but it did not affect the assets I already have in production.

Comment: Yes.. because the assets is different from your access permission. The assets are the object and your .update method requires access permission. In this case, the assets exist and your access permission does not exist. That's why you cannot update the asset in your s3 bucket

Comment: @KendrickKesley, I think you provided the answer then. I recreated the access key and was able to upload the new image. So, if you want to paste your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you confirm if the access key id is present in your production site? and whether the IAM role exists or not. And whether the access key in the IAM role exist or not. If you confirmed that, check that if your application really use that access key id and not other profiles.

The assets is different from your access permission. The assets are the object and your .update method requires access permission. In this case, the assets exist and your access permission does not exist. That's why you cannot update the asset in your s3 bucket.

Based on your comment, it seems that recreating the access key in the IAM role is the solution.

Although, if you're using AWS product as the production server, try using roles instead of IAM credentials as it doesn't require any access key. Thus, one can say that it's more secure.